# Rigid Body Sim: INTENTIONALLY breaking a chain, falling naturally...kinda

Tags: mesh, objects, rigid-body-simulation

I want to have the chain break at link #2, and have the rest of the chain fall naturally. They start falling, then kind of hover. I've scaled the links up to 4.5' tall, and they still hover in the middle section of the chain after falling for a few frames. I have tried this in 2.78/9.
[image: Chain links hovering]

I'm new to the site, thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: [Here Is a link](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) To the place where you upload your blend file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think to have finally found what is causing that behaviour: you set a X+Y rotation lock on most chain rings...

Eg: the first one from top has free movement:

[image]

While most chain rings have X and Y rotation locked, as you can also see from the rotation manipulator:

[image]

To correct, select all chain rings, then - keeping <kbd>ALT</kbd> pressed - you toggle X and Y rotation locks for all selected objects.

In this way your rigid body simulation should work better...

[image]

Comment: YES! Thank you! I had forgotten I had locked the rotation for a previous animation! You rock, thanks again!